# Algebraic curves covering only one curve of positive genus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a positive integer $g$ can you write down an algebraic curve of genus $g$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that covers only one curve of positive genus (i.e. itself)?

Comment: By covering I mean a dominant possibly ramified morphism.

Comment: No I want a curve $C$ such that if $D\neq C$ is a curve of positive genus then any map $C\to D$ is constant

Answer (score 2):

Almost any curve of genus $g>1$ will verify what you ask for (in the sense that most curves verify this, so if you choose one at random it will verify this). Only need the jacobian of the curve to be simple over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the curve cannot cover any curve of genus $g'>0$ with $g>g'$, and if it covers a curve of genus $g$, then it must be the identity covering.

For example, you can choose one polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d>4$ with integer coeficients (and wihout multiple roots), and consider the hyperelliptic curve given by $y^2=p(x)$. Computing the discriminant you can find primes of good reduction (the ones not dividing the discriminant). If for one of such primes $p$ the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius (that can be computed by computing the rational points on  the fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ for $q=p^n$ for $n=1,2,\dots,g$) is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the Jacobian over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is simple and hence the same is true over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Of course you can also ask the curve not to cover any other genus $g'>0$ curve over $\mathbb{C}$. This can also be acomplished by priving the Jacobian is simple over $\mathbb{C}$,  but one needs stronger arguments to show this than to reducing modulo some primes.

Comment: Is the Jacobian being simple known to be a generic condition for $g \gg 0$?

Comment: By dimension counting in the moduli space, it should be true gor all $g>0$...

Comment: My recollection, from a talk of Zarhin, is that if the Galois group of $p(x)$ is the symmetric group, then $y^2=p(x)$ is such a curve. It does take work though. Over $\mathbb{C}$, one can see that the set of "bad" curves is a countable union of proper Zariski closed sets in moduli. Then use Baire category....